# Displaying selected column and result queried by SQL web form using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a local database file that I want an html webform to query on.The webform contains a text field where the user enters a SQL query and submits, this is saved as $sql in the code below. I was able to do this if the query is "SELECT * from rc3 .." since all columns are displayed. But if the user select individual columns such as "SELECT new_ra , rc3_ra FROM  rc3...." then the script errors because  the other columns are not retrieved. I know there's a way to do this by fetching the column, but I am not sure why mysql_fetch_array,mysql_fetch_field don't work.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Query Results Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    $sql= $_POST['sql'];
    echo "Search by PGC number </br>";
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:rc3.db');
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();
    echo "<br>Result for:<br>".$sql."<br>";
    echo "<br><table style='width:300px' border='1' cellpadding='10px'>  ";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>PGC</td>";
    echo "<td>rc3_ra</td>";
    echo "<td>rc3_dec</td>";
    echo "<td>rc3_radius</td>";
    echo "<td>new_ra</td>";
    echo "<td>new_dec</td>";
    echo "<td>clean</td>";
    echo "<td>error</td>";
    echo "<td>in SDSS footprint</td>";
    echo "<td>Low surface structure image</td>";
    echo "<td>Poster image</td>";
    echo "<td>ufits</td>";
    echo "<td>gfits</td>";
    echo "<td>rfits</td>";
    echo "<td>ifits</td>";
    echo "<td>zfits</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetchObject())
    {  
        echo "<tr>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->PGC)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->rc3_ra)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->rc3_dec)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->rc3_radius)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->new_ra)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->new_dec)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->clean)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->error)."</td>";
        echo " <td>".htmlspecialchars($row->in_SDSS_footprint)."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($row->low)."'download='".htmlspecialchars($row->low)."' target='_blank'>".explode("/", htmlspecialchars($row->low))[2]."</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($row->best)."'download='".htmlspecialchars($row->best)."' target='_blank'>".explode("/", htmlspecialchars($row->best))[2]."</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($row->ufits)."'download='".htmlspecialchars($row->ufits)."' target='_blank'>".explode("/", htmlspecialchars($row->ufits))[2]."</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($row->gfits)."'download='".htmlspecialchars($row->gfits)."' target='_blank'>".explode("/", htmlspecialchars($row->gfits))[2]."</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($row->rfits)."'download='".htmlspecialchars($row->rfits)."' target='_blank'>".explode("/", htmlspecialchars($row->rfits))[2]."</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($row->ifits)."'download='".htmlspecialchars($row->ifits)."' target='_blank'>".explode("/", htmlspecialchars($row->ifits))[2]."</a></td>";        
        echo "<td><a href='".htmlspecialchars($row->zfits)."'download='".htmlspecialchars($row->zfits)."' target='_blank'>".explode("/", htmlspecialchars($row->zfits))[2]."</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
    echo "<table>";

 ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you mentioning MySQL?

Comment: Isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PDO in a while so there might be a slightly cleaner way to do this, however, this should still work:

```
$sql = $_POST['sql'];
echo "Search by PGC number </br>";
$db = new PDO('sqlite:rc3.db');
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
echo "<br>Result for:<br>" . $sql . "<br>";
echo "<br><table style='width:300px' border='1' cellpadding='10px'> <thead>  ";


$firstRun = TRUE;

$links = array('low', 'best', 'ufits', 'gfits', 'rfits', 'ifits', 'zfits');

while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {

    if ($firstRun !== FALSE) {

        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $th => $val) {
            echo "<th>$th</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        $firstRun = FALSE;
    }

    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {

        $row_value = htmlspecialchars($value);

        if (in_array($key, $links)) {
            $link_val = explode('/', $row_value);
            echo '<td><a href="' . $row_value . '" download="' . $row_value . ' target="_blank"">' . $link_val[2] . '</a></td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>' . $row_value . '</td>';
        }
    }
    }

    echo '</tr>';


    echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

hope this helps!